# How to send data from jsp page to controller using jqgrid in spring

Tags: spring, jqgrid

```
var pid = $('#byId').val();

jQuery("#patient").jqGrid({
    mtype: 'GET',
    url : "totalPatientList.html",
    postData :{pid:pid},
    datatype : "json",
    colNames : [ 'Patient Id', 'Name', 'BirthDate', 'Address','City','Mobile' ],
    colModel : [ {
        name : 'patientId',
        index : 'patientId',
        width : 55
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        index : 'name',
        width : 200
    }, {
        name : 'birthdate',
        index : 'birthdate',
        width : 100,
        editable : true
    }, {
        name : 'address',
        index : 'address',
        editable : true,
        width : 80
    }, {
        name : 'city',
        index : 'city',
        editable : true,
        width : 80
    }, {
        name : 'mobile',
        index : 'mobile',
        editable : true,
        width : 80
    } ],
    rowNum : 10,
    rowList : [ 5, 10, 30 ],
    pager : '#pager',
    sortname : 'id',
    viewrecords : true,
    sortorder : "desc",
    caption : "Search Patient's List",
    width : 800,
    cellEdit : true,
});
```

I have a code like above.

I want to send `pid` from this JSP page to controller.I am getting `pid` , but when I reload my web page. I want it without reloading the page when i click the button.

How can I do that?

plz plz help me....

Comment: ajax it , you should be able to do it

Comment: @Satya I dont want to use ajax. I just want to use jQgrid to display data in grid view.

Comment: "I want it without reloading the page when i click the button" = Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "function" style of `postData`:

```js
url: "totalPatientList.html",
postData: {
    pid: function () {
        return $('#byId').val();
    }
}
```

In the case the value for the `pid` parameter will be new evaluated on every request to the server. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more details. In the way you can send multiple parameters to the server by including multiple methods in `postData` object.